# Jasmine HtmlReporter calls itself, finds itself undefined

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I am testing a Backbone Marionette application. The test page consists of the following scripts:

- Jasmine: `<script src="../testing/lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine.js"></script>`
- Jasmine HTML reporter: `<script src="../testing/lib/jasmine-1.3.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>`
- My spec: `<script src="js/app.spec.js"></script>`
- Setup: window.onload code copied [exactly from the Jasmine github page](http://pivotal.github.io/jasmine/#section-27)

The odd part is, I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'SuiteView' of undefined
```

I looked at the stack trace. `jasmine.HtmlReporter` gets ready to output the test summary after all tests complete. It calls `jasmine.HtmlReporterHelpers.appendToSummary`, where `jasmine.HtmlReporter` is `undefined`, as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

An object method cannot find itself. How can this even happen?

Comment: This step you have explained is very basic which should work straight forward, if you still facing the issue, can you update the app.spec.js content or sample on which you are facing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'SuiteView' of undefined

`SuiteView` is a property of the currently executing suite, which in this case is missing. Jasmine has the following lifecycle:

```
var jasmineEnv = jasmine.getEnv (); //Initialize Environment
jasmineEnv.updateInterval = 1000;
var htmlReporter = new jasmine.HtmlReporter (); //Initialize Reporter
jasmineEnv.addReporter (htmlReporter); //Add Reporter
jasmineEnv.execute (); //Start Suite
```

Here is a full script:

```
<script>
function load()
  {
  var description = location.hash.match(/".+"/).toString().replace(/"/g,"");
  var spec = location.hash.match(/function.+}/).toString();
  var result = Function("return " + spec)();
  var len = jasmine.getEnv().topSuite().children.length;
  var test;
  var suite;
  var suite_name;
  var reporter_args;
  var reporter_methods;
  var i;

  test = jasmine.getEnv().it(description, result);
  suite = jasmine.getEnv().topSuite().children[len];
  reporter_args = jasmine.HtmlReporter.toString().match(/options\.[a-zA-Z]+/g);
  reporter_methods = jasmine.HtmlReporter.toString().match(/this\.[a-zA-Z]+/g)
  var suite_name = suite.fullname;
  for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
    jasmine.getEnv().topSuite().children.shift();
    }
  jasmine.getEnv().execute(suite_name);
  }
</script>
```

**References**

- [Step by Step Guide for Unit Testing ExtJS Application using Jasmine](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/744686/Integrating-Jasmine-and-Selenuim-for-Web-UI-Testin)
- [Integrating Jasmine and Selenium for Web UI Testing](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/744686/Integrating-Jasmine-and-Selenuim-for-Web-UI-Testin)
- [Drying up Jasmine Specs with Shared Behavior](https://blog.pivotal.io/labs/labs/drying-up-jasmine-specs-with-shared-behavior)
- [JavaScript-Jasmine-Unit-Test-Example/jasmine-unit-tests-runner.html at master · JesterXL/JavaScript-Jasmine-Unit-Test-Example](https://github.com/JesterXL/JavaScript-Jasmine-Unit-Test-Example/blob/master/jasmine-unit-tests-runner.html)
- [jasmine-standalone-requirejs/README.md at master · pirelenito/jasmine-standalone-requirejs](https://github.com/pirelenito/jasmine-standalone-requirejs/blob/master/README.md)
- [AngularJS Starter with Jasmine unit testing integrated (for usage in "http://plnkr.co/")](https://gist.github.com/evangalen/5077594)
- [Integrating the Jasmine test runner for Chrome extension development](https://gist.github.com/ecmendenhall/3740896)
- [esbie/jasmine-bootstrap: A Jasmine HTML runner that uses Twitter's Bootstrap to look beautiful](https://github.com/esbie/jasmine-bootstrap)

Comment: url for **Step by Step Guide for Unit Testing ExtJS Application using Jasmine** is incorrect. I think you are referring to:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/662832/Step-by-Step-Guide-for-Unit-Testing-ExtJS-Applicat